# ORA-01722: Invalid Number, find specific line

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a rather large select which throws the `ORA-01722: Invalid Number`  error. The error itself is clear but I don't know the exact line which throws it.

Is there any way to find out the exact line? I don't really want to look through the whole select and compare the types as it would take a very lone time.

Comment: In what environment are you executing the query?

Comment: Please share your query. We will try to find that on your behalf.

Comment: Not easily. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=aa0d64fea9769afb7bd29db6834453f4) shows that Oracle does not always report the line number and even when it does report a line number (in PL/SQL) it might refer to where a cursor is first used rather than where the SQL statement is created.

Answer (score 0):

Most SQL clients will report the line and column where the error happened.  If you don't have a good IDE handy, use `DBMS_SQL`.

### SQL Client

Most SQL IDEs will highlight the line and column number of the error.  Even SQL*Plus shows exactly where the invalid number error occurs:

```
SQL> select *
  2  from dual
  3  where 1 = 1
  4  and 1 = 'a'
  5  and 2 = 2;
and 1 = 'a'
        *
ERROR at line 4:
ORA-01722: invalid number
```

(Unfortunately, Oracle SQL Developer does not provide this functionality.)

### DBMS_SQL

If your choice of SQL tools is limited, you can still find the relevant line number using `DBMS_SQL.LAST_ERROR_POSITION`.

```
declare
    v_sql clob := q'[
        select *
        from dual
        where 1 = 1
            and 1 = 'a'
            and 2 = 2
    ]';
    v_cursor integer;
    v_ignore number;
begin
    v_cursor := dbms_sql.open_cursor;
    dbms_sql.parse(v_cursor, v_sql, dbms_sql.native);
    v_ignore := dbms_sql.execute(v_cursor);
exception when others then
    dbms_output.put_line(sqlerrm);
    dbms_output.put_line('Error starts here: '||
        substr(v_sql, dbms_sql.last_error_position));
end;
/

Results:
ORA-01722: invalid number
Error starts here:  'a'
            and 2 = 2
```

(This answer assumes you can directly run the SQL statement.  If the error is part of a PL/SQL program, then there's no easy way after the fact to find the line number inside a SQL statement, unless you're able to run it again through `DBMS_SQL`.  The exact context is important here.)

Answer (score -1):

You have to do a binary search (ticking out half of columns, filter half of data) to find the column and line where the failure occures. Unfortunately there is no better way to debug a single SQL statement

Comment: There are a few ways to get this information (depending on the precise context), see my answer for details.

Comment: Ok didn't know that for where clauses this information is provided. In most times I got this error it was in converting select lists ... @thatjeffsmith any idea how to configure SQL-Developer that error line for SQL-Statements is provided.

Answer (score -1):

In most cases I've met there were 2 reasons for such a behaviour. Both are in WHERE area

1. When comparing a number against a string column, e.g.

   where order_num = 2000

having order_num column defined as varchar2. In this case the execution crashes when it comes to order number like "1689_new" or so.

2. when comparing a number column against a string column,

   where name = age

In the second case I got columns with similar name (table.order_num and table1.order_num) but having different datatype (varchar2 and number)

So I always check filter condition by commenting them out. 
First the hard coded values (see 1, above), then the column names.

The all_tab_cols is helpful for quick datatype check