# How to get exact error line in an Oracle SQL query?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm working with an Oracle Database (SQL Developer as client) and long queries (*most of them having between **5k and 10k lines**, with the longest reaching 60k lines*).

**My objective would be that when running the queries on SQL Developer, I can see the exact line where the error occurs.** Currently SQL Developer/Oracle DB shows the error type (ex. "missing expression" or "missing right parenthesis") but doesn't show where is the error, forcing me to analyze every bit of the query.

Is there a way to let the Database show the error line or there's nothing I can do? (*Nope, I can't reduce the query's size since they come from an external source; I just need to make sure they work and fix any errors*). I've also already tried with other clients (VSCode, Toad, DBeaver).

---

Example:
Running the following query:

```
SELECT
'Line 1' as column_1,
'Line 2' as column_2,
CASE WHEN 1= THEN ELSE NULL as column_3,
'Line 4' as column_4,
'Line 5' as column_5
FROM dual;
```

would correctly show where the error is ("*Error at Line: 4 Column: 14*") but this does not happen when running long queries. If you want to test a longer query, I've used [this](https://pastebin.com/5X64UPX5) 5000-lines query as test, which doesn't show where the error is (*spoiler: line 2507*).

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: a **MINIMAL** query as part of the question (not hidden behind an external link that may or may not link to a virus-ridden spam website). When I say minimal, I mean that if you can explain the problem in a query of 5 lines then use that instead of one with thousands of lines.

Comment: You need to `end` a case expression. And what is `1= then` supposed to mean?

Comment: @Isolated You appear to have missed the point of the question. It is **NOT** how to fix this specific query; it is how to get Oracle and/or SQL Developer to report which line within the statement the error occurs (and not the line that is the first line of the statement).

Comment: @MT0 I was thrown off by the significantly long example that didn't follow _minimally reproducible data_. The OP just edited, which makes it more clear now IMHO.

Comment: I've just edited the post to include an example. However, it is impossible to show what I'm struggling with with a small query.

Comment: 5K-10K lines is not reasonable for query length. That will take forever to parse and use a huge amount of shared pool memory for the cursor. Not to mention making debugging hard as you've discovered. I'd suggest rearchitecting what you're doing so that reasonably sized queries suffice.

Comment: As for the line number, if you submit this as SQL your error stack should tell you the line number. If you are submitting it within a PL/SQL block, it will only point to the first line. If this is what's happening, run it standalone outside of PL/SQL. If it's a tool issue, try using SQLPlus or another tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clicking on the  **Query builder** in **SQL developer** will show you the exact line where the error has occurred.
I used the sample SQL you provided and got the below output.
**Please also note query builder will not identify whether table or view does not exists or not, it will only validate the SQL syntax.**

[image]

**Edit1**:-You can also use DBMS_SQL.LAST_ERROR_POSITION to identify the error line. The link below

[ORA-01722: Invalid Number, find specific line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59749066/ora-01722-invalid-number-find-specific-line)

Comment: This doesn't catch all types of errors but it's probably the best solution so far!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know in over 20 years, when having some SQL statment in some stored program unit or anonymous PL/SQL block, you can't get the exact line where there is some missing expression or brackets or whatever.
What you can do is to have a log where to log the errors and handle the exceptions the following way:

```
begin
  insert into ( ---
  )
  select ...
  ...
exception
  when others then 
    v_errmsg:=sqlcode||':'||sqlerrm;
    v_other_info:=... --- here you compose a string with relevant info for debug
  log_runs(
    p_errlevel => 0
    ,p_program => $$plsql_unit
    ,p_line => $$plsql_line
    ,p_msg => v_errmsg
    ,p_other_info => v_other info
  );
  raise;
end;
```

And your logging procedure will look like below:

```
procedure log_runs (
    p_errlevel number
    ,p_program varchar2
    ,p_line => number
    ,p_msg => varchar2
    ,p_other_info => varchar2
  )is
  pragma autonomous_transaction;
begin
  if config_pkg.get_error_level>p_errlevel then
    return; --- log nothing if the settings for logging level is greater
  end if;
  insert into runs_log (
    log_time,
    program_unit,
    program_line,
    errlevel,
    message,
    other_info
  ) 
  select
   sysdate log_time
   p_program program_unit,
   p_line program_line,
   p_errlevel errlevel,
   p_msg message,
   p_other_info other_info
  from dual;
  commit;
end;
```

Thus you may have all the elements do discover what went wrong on a particular SQL statement.

Answer (score -1):

Well, my SQL Developer (right), as well as SQL*Plus (left) (to stay with Oracle) shows error point:

[image]

I believe your tool(s) should do the same. If not, could you post your own screenshot so that we wouldn't have to guess?

Comment: No, that wasn't the point of my question. I'm having trouble with long queries (3000 lines or more).

Comment: Aha; so, you're saying that SQL Developer doesn't display that info if query is very long? What does it display, then? Screenshot, please?

Comment: It shows exactly what it's in your screenshot (right side) but without the text "Error at Line: 4 Column: 14"

Comment: I see; so I created an example - a query with some 10.000 lines, put an error at the end and - you are right! - no error position any more!. After some more testing ("moving" error up the code), it turns out that error position is displayed when error line is somewhere between 2600 and 3900 line or 130.000 to 160.000 characters of code. I have no idea what it depends on. Google doesn't return anything (or I don't know what to search for). I wish @thatjeffsmith sees this question; he's the SQL Developer expert, so I hope he might help.